# Bootstrap 5 Tabs and mySQL data refresh

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, tabs

I am building a test (learning) app using bootstrap 5, PHP, js ajax and mySQL. I have a mySQL table of students and I'm making use of three tabs to show the same data but in a different sort order: by id, by name and by course.

I have the following code:-

```
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">

    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="by-id" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="by-id-tab">
    <?php StudentOrder("id"); ?>
    <table id="by-id-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            require 'dbcon.php';
            $sort_var = "id";
            $query = "SELECT * FROM students2 ORDER BY $sort_var";
            echo $query;
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
            {
                foreach($query_run as $student)
                {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $student['id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $student['name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $student['email'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $student['phone'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $student['course'] ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" value="<?=$student['id'];?>" class="viewStudentBtn btn btn-info btn-sm">View</button>
                            <button type="button" value="<?=$student['id'];?>" class="editStudentBtn btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" value="<?=$student['id'];?>" class="deleteStudentBtn btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

...
```

To avoid a repetition of this code for each tab-content it seems reasonable to call a php function in the same way as I'm calling:-

```
<?php StudentOrder("id"); ?>
```

But instead of just doing:-

```
<?php
function StudentOrder($sort_var) {
$html = "<h3>List of Students: by " . $sort_var . "</h3>";
echo $html;
}

?>
```

The function should perform all the table html and mySQL code with the only difference being:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM students2 ORDER BY $sort_var";
```

However, when I implement this the tab content doesn't show the correct content, they are always sorted by ID.

The next solution is to try some ajax in a tab onclick event against each tab. Is this the way to go or are there alternative solutions?